# Spring define a bean in session scope with java config

Tags: java, spring, rest, javabeans

I would like to use a bean in session scope, but I receive an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\testRestService\WEB-INF\classes\test\server\config\AppConfig.class];
nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean.autowire()
```

The Person Bean:

```
public class Person {
//This is a Pojo
//...
}
```

The AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("test.server")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(scope = DefaultScopes.SESSION)
    @ScopedProxy
    public Person getPerson() {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

The Person Sercive:

```
@Component
public class PersonService implements IPersonService {

    @Autowired
    protected Person person;

    @Override
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }
}
```

The PersonController:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonService personService;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Person.class, new GenericEditor<Person>(Person.class));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/setPerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setPerson(@RequestParam(value = "person") Person person) {
         this.personService.setPerson(person);
         return "Person: " + person + " saved.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Person getPerson() {
         return this.personService.getPerson();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `@Scope("session")` on the Person bean, in this case I did not use the `@ScopedProxy` annotation in appconfig and used the `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean("person")` instead of `org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean(scope = DefaultScopes.SESSION)`. In this case I didn't receive an error, but the Person bean wasn't in the session scope when I tested it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to be able to set person like you are doing (`setPerson`), you will need `PersonHolder` object. When you do `this.person = person;` you are replacing the initially autowired scoped proxy with some other instance.

Comment: Thank you, I changed that code to 
    @Override
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person.setAge(person.getAge());
        this.person.setName(person.getName());
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session level beans are supported through JDK dynamic proxies. The following modifications are required in your code:

- remove the getPerson() method from the AppConfig class
- do not autowire your bean in PersonService, just instantiate it with it's default constructor
- annotate the PersonService with the following:

  - **@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)**

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the classes which bean has scope as follow:

@Scope(value = [scope], proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

> Proxy Mode TARGET_CLASS: is used for creating AOP proxy of the bean.
>   We must do it when injecting short lived bean scope (request,
>   session…) to long lived bean scope (singleton, prototype) or injecting
>   prototype to singleton scope.

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class Address {
    private String address = "US";

    public Address() {
        System.out.println("Create new Address: " + this.address);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}


@Component
public class Customer {

    @Autowired
    private Address address;

    public String getCustomerAddress(){
        return address.getAddress();
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress(String address){
        this.address.setAddress(address);
    }


}
```