# Spring responsible for hibernate session : invalid default: org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I straggle a lot with creating simple context in spring to make it take care of hibernate stuff. You can find my project [here](https://github.com/jjpikoov/pizzaa).

Error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7536 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/intellijidea-ce/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.1.1 clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.pizzaa.application.App
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building application 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ application ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/jjpikoov/IdeaProjects/pizzaa/application/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ application ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jjpikoov/IdeaProjects/pizzaa/application/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ application ---
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /home/jjpikoov/IdeaProjects/pizzaa/application/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ application ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.scopedProxy()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:612)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
```

Here I am creating context:

```
package com.pizzaa.application;

import com.pizzaa.application.interfaces.AdminService;
import com.pizzaa.domain.admin.Admin;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 5/14/16.
 */



public class App {

    public static void main(String [] args) {


//        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(Config.class);
        context.refresh();
        AdminService adminService = (AdminService) context.getBean("adminService");

        Admin a1 = new Admin();
        a1.setLogin("jjpikoov");
        a1.setPassword("jjpassw");
        a1.setEmail("emailjj");

        adminService.addAdmin(a1);

        context.close();
    }
}
```

Config:

```
package com.pizzaa.application;

import com.pizzaa.infrastructure.dbrepository.AdminRepositoryIM;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 5/31/16.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AdminRepositoryIM.class, AdminServiceIM.class, SpringConfiguration.class})
public class Config {
}
```

SpringConfig:

```
package com.pizzaa.application;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 5/31/16.
 */

//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AdminRepositoryIM.class, AdminServiceIM.class})
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.pizzaa.domain"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pizza");
        dataSource.setUsername("jjpikoov");
        dataSource.setPassword("pizza"); //bad practise!!!!
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("connection_pool_size", 1);
        properties.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.put("show_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sf){
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sf);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.pizzaa.application;

import com.pizzaa.application.interfaces.AdminService;
import com.pizzaa.domain.admin.Admin;
import com.pizzaa.domain.admin.repository.AdminRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 5/4/16.
 */

@Service("adminService")
@Transactional
public class AdminServiceIM implements AdminService {

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

//    public AdminServiceIM(){
//        this.adminRepository = new AdminRepositoryIM();
//    }

//    public AdminServiceIM(AdminRepository adminRepository){
//        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
//    }

//    @Transactional
    public List<Admin> getAllAdmins() {
        return adminRepository.findAll();
    }

//    @Transactional
    public void addAdmin(Admin a) {
        this.adminRepository.insert(a);
    }

//    @Transactional
    public boolean removeAdmin(int id) {
        return this.adminRepository.delete(id);
    }

//    @Transactional
    public Admin getAdmin(int id) {
        return this.adminRepository.find(id);
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
package com.pizzaa.infrastructure.dbrepository;

import com.pizzaa.domain.admin.Admin;
import com.pizzaa.domain.admin.repository.AdminRepository;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 5/30/16.
 */

@Repository
public class AdminRepositoryIM implements AdminRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void insert(Admin x) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(x);
    }


    public boolean delete(int id) {
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Admin a = s.byId(Admin.class).load(id);
        s.delete(a);

        if (a == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public Admin find(int id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().byId(Admin.class).load(id);
    }

    public List<Admin> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Admin.class).list();
    }

//    public List<Admin> findAll() {
//        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Admin.class).list();
//    }
}
```

Domain:

```
package com.pizzaa.domain.admin;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by jjpikoov on 4/9/16.
 */
@Entity
@Table
public class Admin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I tried almost everything. Do you have any idea what I've done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring define a bean in session scope with java config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698266/spring-define-a-bean-in-session-scope-with-java-config)

Comment: I don't think so, I have seen it before.

Comment: So you have tried that solution?!!

Comment: Mixing versions of spring jar.

Comment: this looks like a version incompatibility issue. Please reply with a) what version of JavaConfig you are using and b) what version of Spring you are using.

Comment: [My maven](https://github.com/jjpikoov/pizzaa/blob/master/application/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

It is version problem.

Remove `@Configuration` from your bean class. Hope it will solve your issue.

Resource Link:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/attic/spring-javaconfig/66864-exception-while-loading-javaconfigapplicationcontext